# Создание приложения на Android

Tags: eclipse, android, java

Начал разбирваться с программированием на java под Android. Создал свой первый проект. Вот код для файла src/StartActivity.java

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

пишет две ошибки

```
R cannot be resolved to a variable StartActivity.java /Life/srс/com/example/life line 11 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable StartActivity.java /Life/src/com/example/life line 16    Java Problem
```

проект в принципе пустой, без изменений, лайаут main существует, так же как и xml-файл menu/main.xml, в выскакивающих подсказках для R.layout. и R.menu. нет main-ов. В чем может быть проблема? SDK стоит последний, так же как и плагины Android для Eclipce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R.java генерируется при совпадении 2-х условий:

1. Есть чего генерировать - то есть хотя бы один layout или drawable или string
2. Если в ресурсах нет ошибок (или как вариант правильно составлен манифест)

Например, если в ресурсе завести нечто вроде:

```
<LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="match_parent" 
>
```

то под старой SDK<8 R.java не сгенерируется и [aapt - Android Application Packaging Tool](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html) будет ругаться на неизвестный ему атрибут `match_parent` и будет требовать `fill_parent`

Таких подвохов с генерацией R.java много, что и порождает бесконечные ламерско-лузерские дискуссии типа:

> а у меня R.java не генерируется!
> **HELP!!!**

Внимательнее смотрите на исходники мать вашу! IDE кажет/подсвечивает места где есть ошибки! В оконцове возьмите `aapt` и рученьками напустите его на проект.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй руками прям удалить файл R.java.
Если не поможет, то можешь кликнуть праdой кнопкой на проекте - Refresh
или сделать clean проекту.
Что-то точно должно сработать)

Comment: прикол в том, что файла gen/R.java я не наблюдаю, вместо него некий gen/BuildConfig.java, в котором вот че

    package com.example.life;

    public final class BuildConfig {
        public final static boolean DEBUG = true;
    }

его я тоже попробовал удалить, и перечисленное выше проделал, тщетно

Comment: У вас в папке gen лишь только BuildConfig.java лежит?

Если так, то попробуйте так: Project - снимите галочку на build aytomoticaly. Дальше правая кнопка на проекте - build project

Comment: не помогает, все тоже самое, где то нашел, что нужно добавить 

    import android.R

 добавил, появилась другая ошибка 

    main cannot be resolved or is not a field

и R.java так и не появляется

Comment: Сам сейчас попробовал - R.java сам создался.

Может поможет:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896301/r-java-disappears-after-project-clean

Comment: а не можете написать последовательность шагов и выбор параметров, которые вы используете для создания проекта? я просто еще посмотрел в Hello, Android! и тут http://helloandroid.ru/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D1%83/2011/01/06/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%81-android-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-1-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5/ и окно создания проекта совершенно другое у меня

Comment: вообще не важно - попробовал пару разых проектах на разных платформах

Comment: удалил SDK для Android 3.0 и выше, поставил минимальную версию SDK 8 Froyo, и файл R.java появился

Comment: Ну, хорошо, что получилось) Удачи в разработке!